# 06 Jeep Cherokee 8cyl; Auto transmission

Tags: jeep, sensor, throttle, manifold-absolute-pressure-sensor

It seems that I am annually having to replace the “map sensor” and various parts associated with that. Last week I replaced it again, and next will be the “auto throttle body” or something with the vacuum lines.

My Jeep jerks down to lower gears, or stops running altogether. I try to avoid highways and drive in the right lane enable to pull off of the road. Usually, when it sits awhile, it will restart.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is this a "Cherokee" or a "Grand Cherokee"?

Comment: For clarity, you're having to replace parts because of the unreliable running? Is someone advising you that these parts are the required fix?